# Why does this JS file have no effect on DOM?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to teach myself how to modify the DOM using JavaScript. I am at a loss about the following.

This is an HTML snippet.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>A heading</h1>
    <div id="myDIV"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="thejs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML="<p>Try this one comes from script inside html source</p>"
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect to get a similar result from the external js file linked in the script, which contains this:

```js
document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML="<p>While this one comes from a separate JS file</p>";
```

But nothing happens... I realise this is probably silly, I apologize.

Comment: scripts run in order, offcourse when you replace the same value again you will only see the last, this is not an external script problem but an order of scripts problem

Comment: Have you linked to the correct location? Are they in the same directory?

Answer (score 2):

The first script runs and sets the content of the div to "While this one comes from a separate…"

Then, after some time which is imperceptible to a human, passes the second script runs and sets the content of the div to "Try this one comes from script…".

If you want both paragraphs to appear you need to **append** (e.g. with `+=`) the data instead of **replacing** it.

That said, appending chunks of HTML with `innerHTML +=` can cause some issues (it's inefficient as that whole chuck of DOM has to be regenerated and it will blow away inline event handlers) so you are usually better off using [the `insertAdjacentHTML` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead.

Comment: Yet even if I cancel the line within the html nothing happens: ``` <head>
  <title>Just a blank page for adding DOM stuff with JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A heading</h1>
    <div id="myDIV"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="thejs.js"></script>
</html> ```

Comment: Then the problem is likely that the URL is wrong and you need to debug it with the Network tab of the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Almost! There was an EOF somewhere in the js file that prevented it from running correctly. I only saw it in the network tab, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The output depends on where you have included the external js. If you have included it before your embedded script, it will not have any effect, as eventually, it will be overridden by your embedded script. However, if you include the external js after your embedded js, it will work as you want to.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>A heading</h1>
    <div id="myDIV"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="thejs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML="<p>Try this one comes from script inside html source</p>"
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="external.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```